# Send color hex from controller to view without quotes becomes &quot;?

Tags: c#, javascript, json, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I am struggling to send through a value and color pair with JSON, the color value HAS to be returned to the javascript in the view as `color: "#FFFFFF"` for example, and I can send it to the view like that, but the second the browser reads it it becomes `color: &quot;#FFFFFF&quot;` which doesn't work. This is a snippet of my code:

```
values.Add(new StudentBrandsApp.Models.StatsValues() { value = Convert.ToInt32(dr.ItemArray[1].ToString()), color = "#F38630" });

        // populate with some values.
        var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        var writer = new JsonTextWriter(stringWriter);
        writer.QuoteName = false;
        serializer.Serialize(writer, values);
        writer.Close();
        var json = stringWriter.ToString();
        json = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(json);
        ViewData["json"] = json;
```

And in my javascript:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/Chart.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    @{string jsonstring = ViewData["json"].ToString();}
    var data = @jsonstring;

    //Get the context of the canvas element we want to select
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data);
    //Get context with jQuery - using jQuery's .get() method.
    var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
    //This will get the first returned node in the jQuery collection.
    var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx);
    new Chart(ctx).Pie(data, options);
</script>
```

Here is the chart.js documentation on how values and colors should be represented for pie charts: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write `@Html.Raw(jsonString)` to prevent Razor from automatically escaping it.

Comment: Thanks for the response, where shall I add this?